# Elimine una clase pero java la sigue encontrando

Tags: java, eclipse, clase

Tal como dice el título, tenía inicialmente la clase `PantallaConsultaPaciente`, luego creé la clase `PantallaConsultaPaciente2` y eliminé la anterior, pero cuando ejecuto la aplicación desde Eclipse, me sigue levantando `PantallaConsultaPaciente`, la inicial.

Me fijé en el src del directorio dónde tengo alojado el proyecto y no está. Me fijé en ../bin, y sí estaba ese .class, lo eliminé y ahora me larga error cuando ejecuto la aplicación y quiero mostrar la ventana `PantallaConsultaPaciente2`. El error es el siguiente:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: PantallaConsultaPaciente

No sé de dónde lo sigue trayendo. No estoy instanciando `PantallaConsultaPaciente` en ningún lado.

Comment: mira el namespace a ver qué te dice.

Answer (score 4):

Si estas utilizando un IDE como eclipse o netbeans, dale (**project->clean** y luego **clean all project**) esto para eclipse. Y si estas en netbeans dale **click derecho sobre el proyecto** y la opción **clean and build**. Ahora fíjate que al momento que cambiaste de nombre a tu clase No estaba siendo llamado o instanciada en ningún otro lado, si es así el error es por compilación y debes solucionarlo colocando el nuevo nombre de la clase en los lugares que lo estas llamando.

Answer (score 1):

Ese error puede presentarse cuando no utilizas el IDE para renombrar a una clase. Por ejemplo, tienes las clases: `Clase1` y `Clase2`, eliminas la `Clase2`, por medio del IDE, pero a la `Clase1` la seleccionas y le das <kbd>F2</kbd>, para cambiar el nombre a `Clase2`, y le cambias el nombre a la clase de manera manual.

Pero aquí no hiciste un refactor, puedes evitar que el IDE te marque el error, pero no le dirás a JVM que la clase necesita ser recompilada.

En resumen, siempre elimina con el refactor del IDE.
Y es correcto puedes hacer un clean o build.

Comment: Hola @sibok. ¡Bienvenido y gracias por contribuir! Te comento que en vez de hacer aclaraciones sobre tu respuesta en los comentarios, podés [edit] tu respuesta libremente cuando quieras.